# Switch from random order to array order

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i change the order inside the array ? I've got this

```
setColor(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
```

I'd like to sort the order according to the array position and not random. Thanks

Comment: Then replace the "random" part with a simple loop o.O

Comment: Then don't use `Math.random()`. Just use a variable that increments starting from `0`.

Comment: Sorry if that sounds weird but i'm just getting started. My question might seem elementary, i apologize. How can i set a variable or loop?

Comment: Read about Array method sort, and mdn for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See which color is currently being used and switch to the other one.

```
const [color, setColor] = useState(false); //or maybe useState("#ff6700")

function onClick() { 
    const colors = ["#ff6700", "#ffffff"];

    if ( colors.indexOf(color) === 0 ) {
        setColor(colors[1]); 
    } else {
        setColor(colors[0]); 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Basically i have this:   function onClick() {
    const colors = [
      "#ff6700",
      "#ffffff"
    ]
    
    
        setColor(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);

Comment: I am trying to change button background color whenever it is tapped on. Tapped once, gets orange, tapped again, goes back to white.

Comment: @T.M. So you want to just switch between only those two colors or there will be more?

Comment: only two colors

Comment: const [color, setColor] = useState(false);   function onClick() {
    const colors = [
      "#ff6700",
      "#ffffff"
    ]
    
    
        setColor(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);}